# How can I use a PL/SQLregular expression to replace an HTML tag and its contents with a like number of '?s'?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

In Pl/SQL i need to replace something like;

```
'MOUSE RAT <FONT COLOR="#FF0000">DOG</FONT> CAT ELEPHANT'
```

with

```
'MOUSE RAT ????????????????????????????????? CAT ELEPHANT'
```

Basically I need to replace an HTML tag and everything in between with a placeholder of '?' equal to the same length as the string I am replacing. The good news is the tag will always be a font tag.

Will a REGEXP_REPLACE do this?

IF so what does the pattern look like?

Comment: Are you aware that PL/SQL is *exclusively* used in stored procedures? Anything outside a stored procedure/trigger/function is "SQL".

Comment: I was not specifically aware of that, but since this is being put into a function within a package, then I guess PL/SQL is what I am using. I suspect the answer will apply to both SQL as well as PL/SQL then.

Answer (score 0):

[`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#sthref1426) replaces a *pattern*, so whilst it's useful for finding what you want to replace you can't replace the removed string with something of the same length.

The following will replace the HTML:

```
regexp_replace(str, '</?FONT.*>')
```

You then need to add in question marks to the length of the removed string, i.e. the length of the string prior to removal minus the length of the string now.

I'm not really certain there's a good way of going about this unfortunately. You'll have to use a character to notify you that this is where the question marks need to be once the string has been replaced. Something like the following *would* work:

```
replace( regexp_replace(str, '</?FONT.*>', '?')
       , '?'
       , lpad( '?'
             , length(str) - length(regexp_replace(str, '</?FONT.*>', '?')) - 1
             , '?'
               )
         )
```

I really don't like it though... If the entire thing is HTML it would be easier and better to use a proper parser and then you could just replace all the data in the one node.

Answer (score 0):

Although I like **PL/SQL**, I would not recommend that. **PL/SQL** mighty tool for data manipulation but is not too handy for parsing. This is example where Java stored procedure can be more efficient. Especially when you will have to refactor your code several times.

Also `REGEX_REPLACE` works with `VARCHARs`(**max size 32KB**) while you maybe need work with CLOBs.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that is easier to understand than Ben's code, but probably less efficient, and certainly less elegant. I haven't decided which to use, what do you think?

```
  FUNCTION REPLACE_WITH_PLACEHOLDER(IN_STRING IN VARCHAR2, START_STRING IN VARCHAR2, END_STRING IN VARCHAR2, PLACEHOLDER IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    OUT_STRING VARCHAR2(32767);
    START_POSITION BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    END_POSITION BINARY_INTEGER;
    SEARCH_LENGTH BINARY_INTEGER;
    SEARCH_STRING VARCHAR2(500);
    REPLACE_STRING VARCHAR2(500);
  BEGIN
    OUT_STRING := IN_STRING;
    START_POSITION := INSTR(OUT_STRING,START_STRING);
    WHILE START_POSITION > 1
    LOOP
      END_POSITION := INSTR(OUT_STRING,END_STRING,START_POSITION) + LENGTH(END_STRING);
      IF END_POSITION > 0
      THEN
        SEARCH_LENGTH := (END_POSITION - START_POSITION);
        SEARCH_STRING := SUBSTR(OUT_STRING,START_POSITION,SEARCH_LENGTH);
        REPLACE_STRING := LPAD(PLACEHOLDER,SEARCH_LENGTH,PLACEHOLDER);
        OUT_STRING := REPLACE(OUT_STRING,SEARCH_STRING,REPLACE_STRING);
      ELSE
        EXIT;
      END IF;
      START_POSITION := INSTR(OUT_STRING,START_STRING);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN OUT_STRING;
  END REPLACE_WITH_PLACEHOLDER;
```